# Find existing message channel based off participants

Tags: mysql, sql

Here I have a database table schema design as follow:

### channel

- cid
- name

### user

- uid
- name

### participant

- cid
- uid

A message channel is a logical place where users participate in a conversation. Now given a list of uids (for 1-to-1 conversation it's a pair , for multi-participant conversation it's a list) I need to find out if we have already had a channel for the conversation.

For instance, with the following sample data set, given (56, 62), it would return the existing channel with cid=6.

```
mysql> select * from participant;
+-----+-----+
| cid | uid |
+-----+-----+
|   1 |  47 |
|   1 |  17 |
|   2 |  50 |
|   2 |  17 |
|   3 |  53 |
|   3 |  17 |
|   4 |  56 |
|   4 |  57 |
|   5 |  56 |
|   5 |  58 |
|   6 |  56 |
|   6 |  62 |
|   7 |  56 |
|   7 |  53 |
|   8 |  56 |
|   8 |  59 |
|   9 |  56 |
|   9 |  61 |
|  10 |  56 |
|  10 |  63 |
+-----+-----+
20 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> select * from user;
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
| 17 | test17 |
| 47 | test47 |
| 50 | test50 |
| 53 | test53 |
| 56 | test56 |
| 57 | test57 |
| 58 | test58 |
| 59 | test59 |
| 61 | test61 |
| 62 | test62 |
| 63 | test63 |
+----+--------+
11 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from channel;
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | ch1   |
|  2 | ch2   |
|  3 | ch3   |
|  4 | ch4   |
|  5 | ch5   |
|  6 | ch6   |
|  7 | ch7   |
|  8 | ch8   |
|  9 | ch9   |
| 10 | ch10  |
+----+-------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

So the question is, what's the most efficient way in SQL to find the existing channel?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation and `having`:

```
select p.cid
from participant p
group by p.cid
having count(*) = <num users> and
       sum(case when uid not in (<user list>) then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @gordon-linoff, this almost work, except the 3 line, `group by p.id`, I don't have p.id in my schema, did you mean p.cid?

Comment: perfect, this works great and it's efficiently taking full advantage of the MySQL query engine's power to sift through the data.